# pyfacebook + Google App Engine: can't find new functions in facebook.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook, pyfacebook

I'm trying to use the pyfacebook functions (https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) in a Google app engine project. I've followed the advice on the Facebook developer forum (http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=164613) and added the additional functions to the __init__.py file, copied that file to the root directory of my project and renamed it facebook.py. Having imported facebook.py I added the following to the get(self) method for the  Python class for the page:

```
facebookapi = facebook.Facebook(API_KEY, SECRET)

    if not facebookapi.check_connect_session(self.request):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/login.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'apikey': API_KEY}))
        return

    user = facebookapi.users.getInfo(
        [facebookapi.uid],
        ['uid', 'name', 'birthday', 'relationship_status'])[0]

    template_values = {
        'name': user['name'],
        'birthday': user['birthday'],
        'relationship_status': user['relationship_status'],
        'uid': user['uid'],
        'apikey': API_KEY
    }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

When running it I get the following error:

> File "\much\baw08u\Private\IDS\helloworld\helloworld.py", line 54, in get
>
> if not facebookapi.check_connect_session(self.request):
>    AttributeError: 'Facebook' object has no attribute 'check_connect_session'

So it seems to be loading the facebook API fine, but not the new methods I've added. I copied and pasted the code from the developer forum at the bottom of the Facebook class definition, and made sure all the indentation was right but it still doesn't seem to be picking them up. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Have you added methods to facebook.Facebook (supposed to work) or functions to facebook (not supposed to work, unless you use facebook.function_name)?

Comment: Yeah it's all in facebook.Facebook - checked the indentation and everything. Does anyone have a copy of the modified \__init__.py that I could test to see if it is anything to do with syntax?

Comment: Is there a compiled version?  Delete it.

Comment: Nope, deleted all .pyc files, restarted the launcher and the same thing still happens! I've tried it on 2 different computers with the same result. I've found links to a pre-modified version of the file but they're all dead links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You believe the `Facebook` class has a certain method but Python is sure it hasn't. Why? Maybe you misspelled the method name, maybe you did not get the indentation right - hard to say without seeing the code.

You could try poking around to validate your assumptions:

```
import facebook
import logging

logging.warn('Facebook class: %r', dir(facebook.Facebook))
logging.warn('facebook module: %r', dir(facebook))
```

If you are sure you are operating on the correct file, the you should expect to see check_connect_session as a method of Facebook. If you didn't add enough indentation then you expect to see check_connect_method as a function defined in the facebook module. Too much indentation would make check_connect_method a sub function of which ever method precedes it and it won't show up in the above logging. Pay close attention to indentation.

However, a better way to add some custom methods might be:

```
import facebook

class Facebook(facebook.Facebook):
    def check_connect_session(request):
        pass

facebookapi = Facebook(API_KEY, SECRET)

if not facebookapi.check_connect_session(...):
    ...
```

Now when Facebook update their code you simply copy the new file into place - no need to merge your customisations.

Comment: I tried the warning and it said my methods still aren't there. I've tried putting it in different places in the class and it's still not working. Here's a link to my modified facebook.py: the methods are defined starting on line 1944. I've got the feeling I'm staring right at the error but can't see it... http://pastebin.com/wTVYBumB

Comment: Too much indentation :-)  You've created a nested function, not a method.